# Directory Concept in Oracle

Tags: oracle, directory

If we create a directory using create or replace directory and another directory exists which has the same path will the original directory get deleted?

Comment: Oracle directory is just an alias for some operating system path. The path might not even exist. Privileges on Oracle directory have nothing to do with privileges on OS level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can have many oracle directories which point to the same place. Creating or removing an oracle directory does nothing at the OS level, the OS directory doesn't have to exist in order to create the oracle directory.